# .mp3 format piracy protection for PHP

Tags: php, audio, mp3, piracy

I am building an online shop where users can buy audiobooks. All audiobooks consist of .mp3 format files. When user returns from the payment method I have access to payers' SSN (social security number).

At that point I have access to user's account (email, etc.) and his SSN. Now I grant him access to purchased book files. The client is really concerned about piracy and illegal of distribution of audio files online.

To counteract that, we have decided to imprint SSN into the audio file. In case we find an illegal copy, we can track it back to point of origin and tell their parents. So far I have read that there are at least two methods to hide data into .mp3 file- metatags and encryption directly into binary data.

Are there some reliable PHP libraries that would allow me to modify a .mp3 format file's metatag right before download? I have read about PHP's id3 functions (I haven't used them).
Even better- are there some reliable PHP libraries for data encryption into the audio file's binary data?

Any alternatives are also very very welcome!

Comment: Meta tags can be stripped/modified. If someone wants to share a file, they'll find a way to share it.

Comment: I absolutely agree. But not all people are competent to do that. So using meta tags is not a good solution, but at least its something.

Answer (score 2):

mp3 files can be reconverted and their meta-tags stripped.
I suggest you to check if using customer private data (Social security number) for this purpose is legal.

Comment: Data encryption in audio data can survive encoding. Since i'm developing in Estonia, using SSN for that purpose is legal. I am not distributing or giving user private data to any party. At that point only leak of ssn is user distributing illegally audio files. Even in that case SSN at least here, is not much of a secret.